# switch case to return back from Activity to fragment on clicking actionbar home arrow

Tags: android

I got some problem on switch case to return back to the previous fragment from the activity by clicking the home button of action bar. can u please help?my code for onOptionItemSelected is mentioned below.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

   return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'onBackPressed' method (with or without overriding it).

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getFragmentManager().popBackStack()`